# Clone root element retrieved by Snap.load()

Tags: snap.svg

I'm currently tring to figure out how I can re-use the loaded SVG file instead of loading it every time I need it.

```
Snap.load('app/pages/map/desk.svg', function(svg) {
    desk = svg;
});
```

However, when I append this desk variable, it only works the first time, and I figured out that I need to clone the svg in order to re-use it. ([reusing snap.svg loaded svg into different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432367/reusing-snap-svg-loaded-svg-into-different-elements))

Unfortunately svg.clone() does not exists and I cannot do something like svg.select('whatever').clone() because my loaded svg is the root element.

What I simply want is being able to do `desk = svg.clone();`

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried cloning it 'after' you have appended it ? You could also put the svg into a defs element probably and use a 'use' element to reference it as well, which could be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I put a `<defs>` element around the svg and then I select the nested svg and then, every time I append the svg, I call clone on it.

My .svg went from this:

```
<svg>...</svg>
```

to this:

```
<defs><svg>...</svg></defs>
```

And my code looks like this now:

```
// Load the .svg
Snap.load('app/pages/map/desk.svg', function(svg) {
    desk = svg.select('svg');
});

// Append it somewhere
group.append(desk.clone());
```

Thanks for your help @Ian

Comment: I'm not sure you should need to keep cloning it, if it's in a defs statement. You can probably reference it using toDefs()/use(), example at http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-todefs which only has one copy, but 2 separate animations. Otherwise you end up with lots of copies of the same svg. Naturally you may want lots of copies if you are modifying them or something.

Comment: Does it differ in performance then? What's the difference? Also, are you involved in the development of snap? Why is there no such thing as `.toElement()` or `selectRoot()`

Comment: The main difference is that there is just one copy in the DOM, so suppose you have 100 complex svg's, there would be less clutter in there. As to whether it's more performant, it's always difficult to tell as its often down to browser implementation. I'm not a Snap developer, but have played with it. Not sure what you would want toElement to do, or selectRoot() to do specifically, but there's normally a way to do anything that isn't too difficult.